# VB.NET CONVERT BYTE NUMBER TO 8 BIT (256 COLORS) RGB VALUE

Tags: vb.net, colors, data-conversion, 8-bit, 256color

I read this link [Converting 8 bit color into RGB value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338015/converting-8-bit-color-into-rgb-value)

Then I tried the VB.NET code like the following:

```
Private Sub picturebox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, _
                          ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                          Handles picturebox1.MouseDown

    Dim bm As New Bitmap(picturebox1.Image)
    Dim Red As Byte = bm.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).R
    Dim Green As Byte = bm.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).G
    Dim Blue As Byte = bm.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).B

    Dim ColorNumber As Byte = ((Red / 32) << 5) + ((Green / 32) << 2) + (Blue / 64)

    ' Show Byte Number of color
    MsgBox(ColorNumber)

    MsgBox(Red & ":" & Green & ":" & Blue)

    Red = (ColorNumber >> 5) * 32
    Green = ((ColorNumber >> 2) << 3) * 32
    Blue = (ColorNumber << 6) * 64

    MsgBox(Red & ":" & Green & ":" & Blue)


End Sub
```

But when one pixel is selected, an error occurs:

> Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

How do I get a byte value of an image with 256 colors (8 bits), and then restore the (conversion) resulting byte value into the RGB value.

Thanks :)

Comment: You have more than 8 bits of color.

Comment: 256 color images are usually stored using a palette.  In other words, the 8 bit color value is not a combination of RGB, but just a palette index to look up the actual RGB.  8 bits alone is not enough to store RGB.  That would only allow 2 bits per color, which would not be nearly enough.  The acutal RGB value stored in the palette would be larger than 8 bits.

Comment: @SLaks I use images with 256 color BMP format. I edit using microsoft paint.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Is there any example in VB.NET? thanks

Comment: @user2577020 An example of what?  Reading the colors in the palette?  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @StevenDoggart thanks for your answer. I just want to read the color on picturebox in byte format (0-255) and not RGB. And how to set color on picturebox using byte values ​​(0-255) / 256 color?

Answer (score 1):

Your ColorNumber has been declared as a Byte, which can only store values from 0 to 255... Change the code to this:

```
Dim ColorNumber As Int32 = ((Red / 32) << 5) + ((Green / 32) << 2) + (Blue / 64)
```

Also, since you're using .Net you can just get the color with this function:

```
Dim color As Color = Color.FromRgb(Red, Green, Blue)
```

Comment: That's what I'm confused, 256 colors should be 0 to 255 or equal to 1 byte or 8 bits. I want a sample code to retrieve the color value in bytes and can be applied back in the picture. any solution?

Comment: Color information can't be stored as a byte... Yes, 256 colors can be stored as the values 0 to 255, but the values will be just indexes to another struture that contains the real color information (i.e. the palette.) Please check out [this site](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/) for more information.