# How can I lower the bit per pixel of image with OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I need an image with 8 BPP(Bit per Pixel) to learn image segmentation using tensor flow.

Below is my brief code.

```
Mat Image;
Image = imread("Input.png",IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

** image synthesis process **

imwrite("C:\\Output.png", Image);
```

If you're curious about my full source code, you can look at what I asked earlier.

If I check the bpp of the image output in this state, it is 24.

What should I do?

For your information, I've tried making corrections like CV_8UC1, but it doesn't seem to work very well.

Comment: If your output image should be in colour and 8-bit, that almost certainly means you want to create an indexed, a.k.a. palette, image. I show how to do that here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54906864/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably reading in a color image, which has three bytes for the red, green and blue color components of each pixel.

If you just need an 8-bit image, you can use a single color component.

If you need to operate on the input image in a sensible way, [convert it to grayscale](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html) first:

```
cvtColor(src, bwsrc, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, But I wasn't good at asking questions. I want an rgb image of 8 bits. What do I to put in as a parameter?

Comment: 24 bit rgb image -> 8bit rgb image

Comment: @HanSeobKim If you want to convert 24 bit RGB image to 8bit RGB image, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7657742/7514664

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading image in default format, read image in grayscale format.

```
Mat Image;
Image = imread("Input.png",IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

** image synthesis process **

imwrite("C:\\Output.png", Image);
```

You can check this link for detailed information regarding OpenCV image formats: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html